# Will dissolving pure linseed oil in ethanol decrease its drying time?

Tags: solvents

I've looked at some material on the internet and it says that pure linseed oil can take months to dry completely unless a solvent is added, which decreases that time to a few days. I'm wary of industrial solvents due to their toxicity and dangerous fumes, so I was wondering if specifically pure ethanol would be a reasonable and non-toxic alternative to industrial solvents used to speed up the drying time of pure linseed oil.

Comment: What do you mean with drying? What are you applying this to? If you dissolve linseed oil in ethanol and let it sit, the ethanol will evaporate (sooner or later) and you still have the remaining linseed oil.

Comment: Boiled linseed oil contains mineral spirits to help the linseed oil evaporate. I'm just wondering if ethanol could be used instead of mineral spirits. I'm applying the linseed oil to cloth to waterproof it.

Comment: With "dry", you mean solidify, like a resin. The oil does not evaporate. The solvent acts as a plasticiser, until it is finally also evaporated completely. I´ll guess ethanol is gone too quickly. Isopropanol has a slightly higher Bp. If you find nobody who has tried it, you will have do it yourself.

Comment: Warning: Cloth with linseed oil, if not stored well ventilated (hanging, not in a heap!) warms up as long as it is not dry and can self-ignite. But it should rather take a week, not months.

Comment: Strictly speaking linseed oil doesn't "dry" it slowly polymerises. Since the resulting resin is what you want as an end product (since it protects the surface) you have to allow it to happen. Solvents don't much help speed polymerisation up, except to enhance the penetration into the surface.

Comment: @matt_black A plasticiser keeps the resin mobile while polymerising, allowing the reaction to keep going to reach a higher conversion in a given amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Karl has the most scientifically accurate description.  Linseed oil does not dry, it cures.  Drying is an evaporative action where material is lost, linseed oil cures by taking on oxygen atoms to cross-link and cure (pure linseed oil actually gains 17% WT in oxygen as it "dries" making pure linseed oil 100% solids).  Use a polymerized linseed oil (I make Tried & True) to achieve faster curing - raw linseed oil takes 3-4 weeks to cure, our polymerized linseed oil (danish oil) takes about a day with out any of the toxic drying aids.

Raw linseed oil is a non-polar liquid, alcohols are mostly polar, especially the shorter carbon chains like methanol and ethanol.  This makes them very poorly miscible with most oils.  Once you hit a carbon chain of at least 3+ (propyl, isopropyl, butyl alcohol) then the miscibility of linseed in these longer carbon chains increases as the polarity is diminished but you are still better off using a polar solvent, which has 100% miscibility.